# Nullable Fields to Separate Table?

Tags: sql-server, normalization, database-diagrams

My website has a form page that has radio buttons `yes|no` corresponding to 7 questions. When the user selects `yes`, the user needs to specify a value (either a location, name, or medical condition, depending on the question).

However, I'm torn whether I should include the specified values in the same table as the answers.

One one hand, when I include the specified values into the same table as the answers, it is easier to query.

One the other hand, the specified values can have null values (when the user selects `yes`).

I went with the latter and made 7 tables for each of the specified values. Refer to this diagram:

[image: schema]

After looking at the table, I feel it's a bit of an overkill just for a simple functionality.

I would like suggestions as to what route should I go.

**Should I merge everything into one table?**

--OR--

**Should I stick with this diagram?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than stick with that table, would creating a question table work for your application? That is, instead of having a separate table for each question, have a `question` table as

```
CREATE TABLE question (question_id numeric, question text)
```

and instead of the AFE table linking to a bunch of other tables, create a separate `answers` table as

```
CREATE TABLE answers(question_id numeric, afe_id numeric, answer text)
```

That acts as a bridge between `AFE` and `question`. This lets you add new questions easier too.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the diagram as it is. But I would also include the field **afe_id** in the primary key of each referencing table....

According to your needs you may need to record several locations, pending_cases, medical_conditions, and so on for a single afe_id.

You cannot accomplish this with a single row...